# What happened to xmoov?

Tags: php, http, video, streaming, xmoov

I am working on a project in which I need to secure a video (stream) using PHP authentication, and not allow users to download the video. Now, I may be completely wrong here, but I found xmoov to be a perfect fit for this situation. Check user in a MySQL database, and if the user has access, use xmoov to pseudo-stream the video. Block direct file access by using an .htaccess file.

Problem is I can't visit http://xmoov.com/ or find any mirrors for the source code.

Can anyone clarify this or point me in the right direction for an alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is old, but did you find a framework that worked? Looking for one now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it only supports flv. I need one for WebM, OGV and MP4... But the way back machine has it it seems. http://web.archive.org/web/20100102134119/http://xmoov.com/xmoov-php/source/